# Tomcat jdbc pooling with Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, connection-pooling

I am getting this warning:

```
WARNING:[PoolCleaner[661646649:1440675349770]] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.abandon 
Connection has been abandoned PooledConnection[org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@7c9e8e2e]:
java.lang.Exception
```

For the application, I am using spring framework with Tomcat JDBC pooling and Postgres as database. My configuration file :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://ip/db" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="pass" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="validationInterval" value="30000" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60" />
        <property name="logAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
        <property name="initSQL" value="SET application_name = 'app'" />
    </bean>
```

Here is the problem. From my understanding `removeAbandoned` should only abandon connections which are in use more than 60 seconds, that is queries that run more than 60 seconds. I do not have such queries at all. But my connections from pool get abandoned.

I suspect that `removeAbandoned` is removing idle connections in the pool. Though it is not supposed to do so. 
In my application i am getting connection this way:

```
//i am using autowiring.
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource; 
//and in my methods i use it this way: 
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
//and i am closing it after method completion
//maybe i should not??
conn.close()
```

**UPDATE**: I found the error. My Connection variable was global, i made it local to method and everything worked out. Also tested by Apache benchmark, pooling is used. (connections are updated, seen by pg_stat_activity). Thanks for replies.

Comment: why am i getting downvotes? Can you guys at least explain your reasons? So that, next time i will not repeat the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If the connection is not used during `X` seconds (the timeout) and isn't returned to the pool, it's considered to be abandoned, i.e. misbehaving code left a connection open (or rather didn't return it to the pool).

Idle connections aren't abandoned (or at least they very well shouldn't be), since they aren't in use.

It's either a bug in the connection pool (unlikely for such a standard functionality) or somewhere there's a connection being used improperly. It may not be obvious.

You can also monitor the connections from Postgres' side, with `select * FROM pg_stat_activity;`. You should see nicely the ones that are waiting in the pool, since they show the `SELECT 1` validation query.

Comment: no misbehaving code, i made sure that connections are closed. And in spring i do not think there is a way to explicitly return connection to the pool, i.e it is returned automatically, after i close the connection.

Comment: Well closing the connection *is* returning it to the pool, although semi-explicitly. The wrapper class overrides `close()`, so the connection isn't actually closed. Hold on for an edit...

Comment: Kayaman, i am already monitoring connections using that, but thanks for suggestion. Well, i am pretty sure that i am closing the connection. I am checking whether it is closed. [Connection.isClosed()]

Comment: `select * from pg_stat_activity` shows connections which are idle right(connections that are in pool i think)? Does it show abandoned connections? Or it considers abandoned connections as idle?

Comment: Postgres doesn't know about abandoned connections, nor does it care. It's either connected or not. An abandoned connection should show the last query performed and the `query_start` would be up to `timeout` seconds ago. **But** if a connection is checked out of the pool, not used and never returned, it would still show the `SELECT 1` query as the last query.

Comment: I haven't used Tomcat's jdbc-pool, but commons-dbcp provides a stack trace for the place where the `Connection` object was obtained from the pool. That can help you track-down resource leaks, which is likely the cause of these errors.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz If you didn't use Tomcat's jdbc-pool please get off.

Comment: @nikpon I haven't used Tomcat's pool either, do you suggest I get off? Anyways, as Christopher said, there's bound to be logging options for the pool to try to pinpoint the connection behaviours.

Comment: Guys i found the error. My 'Connection' variable was class variable, i made it local to method and everything worked out. Also tested by apache benchmarking, pooling is used. (connections are updated, seen by pg_stat_activity). Thanks for replies. My next question is: Is it a feature or a bug? =)